# как добавить к заметке в веб приложении svg картинку

Tags: c#

Есть веб приложение, на си шарпе с использованием разор и энтити бд
Необходимо сделать чтобы когда мы создавали бы заметку, то к ней прикреплялась бы и так же как и заметка записывалась бы в БД случайная картинка вот с этого апи сайта
https://avatars.dicebear.com/

Comment: Вам не надо чего либо записывать в базу. У любого автора "заметки" должен быть ник, вот его и используйте,  просто подставьте пол автора и ник в эту ссылку `https://avatars.dicebear.com/v2/пол/ник.svg` и отобразите ее например через [img](https://habr.com/company/htmlacademy/blog/337284/).

Comment: так мне нужно чтобы картинка заметки менялась бы в зависимости от самой заметки, скажем если первая заметка, то одна картинка, если вторая заметка, то уже другая картинка

Comment: Ну так сделайте что то уникальное, например `Ник + Id заметки` (`EvgeniyZ907633`), вот вам и уникальные данные для формирования изображения, не надо записывать картинку в базу, у вас для нее и так все есть....